# How to achieve multiple file upload in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on xamarin forms, where I am trying to achieve multiple file upload. What I have tried is using **file picker** plugin which will give me upload one file but my requirement is multiple file upload.

```
//My xaml
<Button Text="Pick File" Clicked="Button_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="Center"  
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
//my C#
var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
```

//MY API (WEB API DOT NET CORE)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RaiseTicket()
{
    //I am sending few object in header those things I am reading here
    var mslAddProviderUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MRaiseTicket>(Request.Headers["mdl"]);

    var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType), _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
    var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);
    //This section variable holds my all files and It is working I have tested using our web application
    **var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();** 
}
```

How to do for multiple files and is there another way to achieve the same?

Comment: Where do you want to upload? Do you want to pick more file once? You could use FileUploader Plugin to upload multiple files at once. Check the code.https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FileUploaderPlugin

Comment: Thank you @WendyZang-MSFT, I want to send it to API, API is already created and it storing file under API project in the folder. So Simply I need to send it to API rest it will take care.

Comment: What is your API? asp.net web API?

Comment: Can you show me what object your API is expecting?

Comment: WendyZang-MSFT and FreakyAli you guys can check I updated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin doesn't implement any cross platform way to pick files, so you either need to implement it yourself using the platform APIs or to find the plugin that does that. As the plugin to pick multiple files doesn't seem to exist, then you need to implement it yourself using native APIs and dependency injection. For example, this is API for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller?language=objc , you need to implement file picker for iOS using this API and then use it from Xamarin using dependency injection (or shared project but it is rarely used today though it is simpler).